# How to put images on top of each other in react.js dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image: tomato card, which when clicked the no. of elements should increase]

[image: This screenshot shows how I want the elements to stack on top each other, so it looks like baskets are kept on each other]

[image: This screenshot shows what I am able to achieve. I have achieved this using "display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse;". So the first element goes to the bottom, 2nd element is placed above the bottom and so on.]

Now, I want to achieve this dynamically, when I click on the tomato card, the number below it increases,so that the basket images are put on each other as in image 2.
I know how z-index works, but I don't know how should I use it to position these images as in image 2.

The image 3 shows what I am able to achieve using "display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse;", so the first  element is at the bottom, the 2nd  element goes above the bottom and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use negative values to the margins between those images.